# HadoopFileSystem load error during TensorFlow installation on raspberry pi3

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi3, python-3.7

[image]screen shot

As Python2.7 will be deprecated on 01/01/2020. I was planning to start using python3. So, I tried to install the tensorflow==1.14.0 on the raspberry pi and it was successful, but when I am loading the Tensorflow for further operations then it throws a load error.

Python - 3.7 (Default installed by Raspbian OS)

Any suggestions why am I facing this issue?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can't install later versions of Tensorflow on the Raspberry Pi using pip. You have to install from source. I made a video doing this: https://youtu.be/GNRg2P8Vqqs

Installing Tensorflow requires some extra steps on the Pi's ARM architecture.

This is how I installed tf 2.0 on my Pi 4:
Make your project directory:

```
cd Desktop
mkdir tf_pi
cd tf_pi
```

Make a virtual environment:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
```

Run the commands based on https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/#usage:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libhdf5-dev libc-ares-dev libeigen3-dev
python3 -m pip install keras_applications==1.0.8 --no-deps
python3 -m pip install keras_preprocessing==1.1.0 --no-deps
python3 -m pip install h5py==2.9.0
sudo apt-get install -y openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev
python3 -m pip install -U six wheel mock
```

Pick a tensorflow release from https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases (I picked 2.0.0). Picking a higher version of Tensorflow (like 2.1.0) requires a higher version of scipy that wasn't compatible with my Raspberry Pi:

```
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v2.0.0/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
python3 -m pip uninstall tensorflow
python3 -m pip install tensorflow-2.0.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

RESTART YOUR TERMINAL

Reactivate your virtual environment:

```
cd Desktop
cd tf_pi
source env/bin/activate
```

Test:
Open a python interpreter by executing:

```
python3 
import tensorflow
tensor.__version__
```

This should have no errors and output: 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today when trying to run the fresh tf installation on my pi 3+