# Python-Tensorflow import Error: HadoopFileSystem load error

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I installed Tensorflow via  `pip3 install tensorflow`. It installed without any Issue but when I try to import it as `import tensorflow as tf` I get the following Error:

> 2020-09-05 14:09:51.687520: E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: libhdfs.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If it matters, I use a Raspberry Pi with Raspian 10 and I use the following tensorflow version:

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.14.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: opt-einsum, absl-py, grpcio, wheel, six, tensorflow-estimator, google-pasta, 
protobuf, termcolor, keras-preprocessing, wrapt, numpy, tensorboard, keras-applications, 
astor, gast
Required-by:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please install from source or try to do as the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59505609/hadoopfilesystem-load-error-during-tensorflow-installation-on-raspberry-pi3)
Remember to choose your appropriate tensorflow version by selecting from [tensorflow options](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases)
I was successful with this solution.